# Improve large query insert performance using MySQL

Tags: php, c++, mysql

I write c++ to do 30000*30000 query MySQL insert

Example

```
for(i=0;i<30000*30000;i++){
// do the MySQL insert
call the function to insert code (maybe just query insert the i value)
}
```

and I am using `mysqlsart()` and `mysqlclose()` sub-function

```
void mysqlstart()
{
        //MYSQL *conn_ptr;
        conn_ptr = mysql_init(NULL);

        if(!conn_ptr)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"mysql_init failed\n");
            //return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        conn_ptr = mysql_real_connect(conn_ptr,"localhost","root","nlpgroup","testdb",0,NULL,0);
}

void mysqlclose()
{
        mysql_close(conn_ptr);
}
```

First time I call the function like

```
mysqlstart();
for loop 
mysqlclose();
```

That will be great in the beginning and after few days I found the error : MySQL server has gone away

And find some solution from internet maybe change max_allowed_packet or some else...

And I don't know what is suitable settings for 30000*30000

And I want to is there something I can change in my code or way to speed up query

Comment: Exactly what goes wrong? What size are your elements? I do believe that MySQL (like most other databases) does what you ask of it, so if you do 30000 * 30000 individual inserts, then it will insert 900000000 times, with whatever overhead there is in IPC between your application and the MySQL db (most likely somewhere between dozen sand several hundred microseconds). Even at 1 microsecond per insert, we're talking 15 minutes. It soon becomes hours, if the time is more than one microsecond per insert. I don't believe there is a way to configure MySQL to merge inserts.

Comment: i use OnlyMAJ that method to do insert and i control every 2000 a data and sent it out , now the problem is not how big data it is ,but the speed up query or the method we should setting in MySQL like my.conf data

Answer (score 1):

You can insert multiple rows at once in this way

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

> INSERT statements that use VALUES syntax can insert multiple rows. To
>   do this, include multiple lists of column values, each enclosed within
>   parentheses and separated by commas. Example:
>
> INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);

Comment: i have tried this and i think 30000*30000 will be really large data

Comment: yes, but you can use 300 insert at each loop. so it decrease 1/300 of your data.I recommend you to use no-sql databases like [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.com/).They have much more scalability than MySQL.

Comment: thanks i will try it ,and now i want to tweak MySQL setting first